# Can I install luxury vinyl planks over ceramic tile?

Tags: ceramic-tile, vinyl-flooring

My existing bathroom floor has tiles like shown in picture. I want to install interlocking luxury vinyl floor planks.

1. Can I do it over existing floor ? if yes, Do I have to fill bevel edges of the tiles with anything to level it ?
2. There are some spots where one or two tiles are not completely leveled with surrounding tiles, Can I chip/sand part of the tiles to level that ?

[image]

Comment: By not completely level, are they raised or sunken?  How much?  Those tiles won't take kindly to be chipped or sanded.

Comment: @crip659 - around 1/4 of centimeter raised near one of the corner.

Comment: It may be easier than you think to remove that tile, and you'll reduce the height offset with the adjacent floor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The imperfections will be felt through the vinyl flooring if you do nothing.

**Option 1:**

You should remove any tiles whose edges are not flush; hammer them, chisel them, whatever.

Next you should pour self-leveling cement and sweep it into all of the grooves. Now you can install the vinyl.

**Option 2:**

Remove all of the tile until you get to the flat sub-floor and install the vinyl.

Removing the tile will be easy if you can get your hands on an SDS-max rotary hammer and use a good chisel.

[image]

**Option 3:**

Lay down 1/8th inch plywood and install the vinyl on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can vinyl plank straight over tile. I did it for a bathroom and it turned out great.

As far as leveling, unless we're talking something massive, I'd just buy a decent waterproof padding. It should cover most of the imperfections. This assumes the floor itself is level. If it's not, you'll need to add some floor leveler first.

To finish the room, I glued vinyl quarter round to the base tiles (I have tile instead of baseboards since the tile extends up the wall).